# Tkinter, como atualizar label no canvas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Olá, estou tentando construir uma tabela dinâmica que atualize os valores automaticamente mas não estou conseguindo atualizar as Labels, estou utilizando o seguinte código:

```
import tkinter as tk


def populate(frame):
    global widgets
    widgets={}

    '''Put in some fake data'''
    tk.Label(frame, text='X',background='white').grid(row=0, column=0,padx=10,pady=5)
    tk.Label(frame, text='K',background='white').grid(row=0, column=1,padx=10,pady=5)
    tk.Label(frame, text='S',background='white').grid(row=0, column=2,padx=10,pady=5)
    tk.Label(frame, text='(%)',background='white').grid(row=0, column=3,padx=10,pady=5)

    for row in range(1,100):

        tk.Label(frame, text="%s" % row, width=3, borderwidth="1", 
                 relief="solid").grid(row=row, column=0)
        t="this is the second column for row %s" %row
        tk.Label(frame, text=t).grid(row=row, column=1)
        tk.Label(frame, text='ANOTHER COLUMN'+str(row)).grid(row=row,column=2)


def onFrameConfigure(canvas):
    '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

table_root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(table_root, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
frame = tk.Frame(canvas, background="#ffffff")
vsb = tk.Scrollbar(table_root, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
canvas.create_window((4,4), window=frame, anchor="nw")

frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event, canvas=canvas: onFrameConfigure(canvas))

populate(frame)

table_root.mainloop()
```

Alguém sabe me dizer como posso atualizar as labels?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

acho que uma solução fácil seria na hora de criar as labels colocar elas em uma lista, já que você esta criando todas elas dentro de um loop for, meio que seria o melhor jeito pra não ter que criar 100 variáveis, algo como

```
def populate(frame):
    label_list = []
    for row in range(1,100):
        ind =tk.Label(frame, text="%s" % row, width=3, borderwidth="1", 
                     relief="solid").grid(row=row, column=0)
        t="this is the second column for row %s" %row
        labelc1 = tk.Label(frame, text=t).grid(row=row, column=1)
        labelc2 = tk.Label(frame, text='ANOTHER COLUMN'+str(row)).grid(row=row,column=2)
        lista = [ind, labelc1, labelc2]
        label_list.append(lista)
```

logo você tem uma lista com o indice, primeira label e segunda label. Dessa forma, caso vc tenha que alterar algum valor em uma linha especifica vc pode usar o indice, caso você for fazer uma atualização de todas as linhas ao mesmo tempo creio que não necessite disso, enfim, para realizar a configuração da label você pode utilizar o .config

```
def troca():
    for x in label_list:
        if x[0]["text"] == '5':
            x[1].config(text = "Olá mundo")
            x[2].conf(text = "Tchau mundo")
```

caso você for atualizar tudo ao mesmo tempo puxando o valor de alguma coisa basta retirar o if e atualizar usando x[1].config e x[2].config.